# SELECT from table with Varying IN list in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-in, xmltable

I am facing a issue in project I am working on, I can not give you actual code but I have created a executable sample code as below

Here `temp` and `temp_id` are two tables

1. `temp` table contains comma separated list of ids which is `VARCHAR2`
2. `temp_id` table contains actual ids which is `NUMBER`

I want to search rows from `temp_id` table by getting `ids` from comma separated list of ids from `temp` table

```
//DDLs to create table
CREATE TABLE temp(ids VARCHAR2(4000));
CREATE TABLE temp_id(data_id NUMBER);

//DMLs to populate test data
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('1, 2, 3');

INSERT INTO temp_id VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO temp_id VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO temp_id VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO temp_id VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO temp_id VALUES(5);
```

**This Query doesn't work**

```
SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN (SELECT to_number(COLUMN_VALUE) FROM XMLTABLE(SELECT ids FROM temp));
```

**Working query**

```
SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN (SELECT to_number(COLUMN_VALUE) FROM XMLTABLE('1, 2, 3'));
```

Here difference between above two queries is I am using column from `temp` table in first query and direct quoted `varchar2` in second query. Not getting the reason why is not working? Is I am missing something? I think there might be some datatype mismatch but not able to figure it out.

Comment: '1, 2, 3' is not a valid number, its a string!

Comment: I did `to_number(COLUMN_VALUE)`. You can check the second query works.

Comment: It is a `Varying IN lists` problem. See my answer.

Comment: Modified the topic title to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirement is called as **Varying IN-lists**. See [**Varying IN list of values in WHERE clause**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/varying-in-list-of-values-in-where-clause/)

**Reason :** `IN ('1, 2, 3')` is **NOT** same as `IN (1, 2, 3)` OR `IN('1', '2', '3')`

Hence,

> SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN(SELECT ids FROM temp);

**is same as**

> SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN('1, 2, 3');

which would thrown an **error** `ORA-01722: invalid number` -

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN('1, 2, 3');
SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN('1, 2, 3')
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL> SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN(SELECT ids FROM temp);
SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN(SELECT ids FROM temp)
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

**NOT same as**

> SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN(1, 2, 3);

which would give you correct output -

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN(1, 2, 3);

   DATA_ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

**Solution :**

For your requirement, you can achieve it like this -

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM temp;

IDS
--------------------------------------------------------------
1, 2, 3

SQL> SELECT * FROM temp_id;

   DATA_ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5

SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT to_number(trim(regexp_substr(ids, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))) ids
  3    FROM temp
  4      CONNECT BY instr(ids, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  5    )
  6  SELECT * FROM temp_id WHERE data_id IN
  7    (SELECT ids FROM data
  8    )
  9  /

   DATA_ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Alternatively, you can create your own **TABLE function** or a **Pipelined function** to achieve this. Your goal should be to [**split the comma-separated IN list into multiple rows**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/). How you do it is up to you!

**Working demo**

Let's take an example of the standard **EMP** table in `SCOTT` schema.

I have a list of jobs in a string, and I want to count the employees for those jobs:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    str VARCHAR2(100);
  3    cnt NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    str := q'[CLERK,SALESMAN,ANALYST]';
  6    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM emp WHERE JOB IN (str);
  7    dbms_output.put_line('The total count is '||cnt);
  8  END;
  9  /
The total count is 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Oh! What happened? The standard emp table should give an output 10. The reason is that the **varying IN list**.

Let's see the correct way:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    str VARCHAR2(100);
  3    cnt NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    str := q'[CLERK,SALESMAN,ANALYST]';
  6    SELECT COUNT(*)
  7    INTO cnt
  8    FROM emp
  9    WHERE job IN
 10      (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
 11      FROM dual
 12        CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
 13      );
 14    dbms_output.put_line('The total count is '||cnt);
 15  END;
 16  /
The total count is 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way in which this might be accomplished, namely by using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT ti.*
  FROM temp t, temp_id ti
 WHERE ',' || REPLACE(t.ids, ' ') || ',' LIKE '%,' || TO_CHAR(ti.data_id) || ',%'
```

(I used `REPLACE()` above to get rid of the extraneous whitespace in the ID list - makes things a bit simpler.) Alternately, one could use `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
SELECT ti.*
  FROM temp t, temp_id ti
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(REPLACE(t.ids, ' '), '(^|,)' || TO_CHAR(ti.data_id) || '(,|$)')
```

[The caret (`^`) and dollar-sign (`$`) characters are to match the start and end, respectively, of the string -- so the ID can either match something at the start of the string (ending with a comma or the end of the string) or something starting with a comma (again, ending with a comma or the end of the string).]