# ORACLE substitute variable in IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM temp t WHERE t.id IN (:IDs)
```

When executed, it prompts me (Oracle SQL Developer) for entering value if IDs variable.

When I enter for example 169, everything runs smoothly, but when I try to enter multiple IDs, like 169,170,171, I get error Invalid Number even while putting it into ''.

I'm used to working with MS SQL and MySQL, so this is little confusing to me.

Anyone any suggestions.

Comment: Seems like Oracle is ANSI/SQL SQL compliant, and both MySQL and SQL Server have some kind of vendor specific extensions.

Comment: @Volt this doesn't work in SQL Server neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `varying-IN list`. In `SQL Developer`, when you are prompted to enter the value for the bind variable, you are simple passing it as `169,170,171` which it is not considering as a `set of values`.

What you could do is, have multiple binds -

`SELECT * FROM temp t WHERE t.id IN (:ID1, :ID2)`

When prompted, enter value for each bind.

**UPDATE** Alright, if the above solution looks ugly, then I would prefer the below solution -

```
WITH DATA AS
  (SELECT to_number(trim(regexp_substr(:ids, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))) ids
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY instr(:ids, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  )
SELECT * FROM temp t WHERE it.d IN
  (SELECT ids FROM data
  )
/
```

Comment: That's really ugly solution, since there can be hundreds of them and I need to pass them at once. :(

Comment: Another way is to use associative arrays. @Volt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885575/passing-an-array-of-data-as-an-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-procedure, assuming your query is in a procedure

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738359/select-from-table-with-varying-in-list-in-where-clause/27739139#27739139 and https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/varying-in-list-of-values-in-where-clause/

Answer (score 0):

If you put them into ", you get error. Oracle doesn't accept ". You should use just numbers without ".
i.e: (169,170,171,...)

Comment: For both values:
1) 169,170,171
2) '169,170,171'
I'm getting error "invalid number"

Comment: You can use first one,can't second one. If your ids are vharchar use like this ('169','170','171')

Answer (score 0):

You can define a substitution variable as an array like so:

```
define IDS = (169,170,171);
```

and then use it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM temp t WHERE t.id IN &IDS;
```