# Query with comma seperated IN parameters in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I wrote the following in Oracle 11g to separate IN params (I_PRODUCT)and make a query. When I give one parameter as the i_PRODUCT, it is populating some results. When  I am inserting multiple comma separated parameters, I am expecting to query one by one and populate the entire result and it is not working.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RQUERY 
(
 I_PRODUCT VARCHAR2
, O_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS BEGIN
O_Cursor := NULL;
OPEN O_Cursor for

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE   
Table1.PRODUCT LIKE ( select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
                     connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);

END RQUERY ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE   
Table1.PRODUCT LIKE ( select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
                     connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

The **LIKE** operator would fail in above query. You need to use **IN**, which would internally be evaluated as multiple **OR**.

```
Table1.PRODUCT IN ( select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
                     connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

Also, regarding [**varying IN list**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/02/varying-in-list-of-values-in-where-clause/), have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739139/3989608).

**Update**

Based on OP's comments.

Modify the query as:

```
WITH str_search AS
(
     select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) pattern from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
SELECT   *
FROM     Table1
WHERE     EXISTS (
          SELECT     NULL
          FROM     str_search
          WHERE     tab.col     LIKE pattern
                 );
```

Comment: I replaced with `LIKE`. No output. I have the PRODUCT Column with values `RETAIL` and `LEASE`. The IN params I'm using to query is `'R%,L%'`

Comment: No, it won't work. See my answer int he link provided. Varying IN list doesn't work in that way. Moreover, you are doing a wild search using LIKE using comma separated values. It will not work.

Comment: Based on your updated code, if I need to use this for multiple IN comma Param quires, do you recommend to create a function and call from there for each parameter (Like `PRODUCT(R%, L%, MODEL(A,B,C), TYPE(G,H,I)'?

Comment: Your updated code is perfect. How to make a common function for multiple queries like this?

Comment: @KodS You can create a function, however, you will need to (ab)use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, as you must do it as dynamic sql where the pattern would come as IN parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use your solution for at least 3 query parameters. I don't know how to copy and use same solution for three params and that is why I am looking to convert this into a function.

Comment: Post a new question, clearly mention what you are trying to do . Post your try so far, I am sure you will get the help required. It is too late at night in my timezone, I would get back tomorrow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151908/comma-seperated-query-for-multiple-parametes-in-plsql

Comment: Ok, I will try. Good night :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE ProcedureName
 (
     I_PRODUCT IN VARCHAR2 :=NULL,
     O_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
 ) 
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE I_PRODUCT_    VARCHAR2(1000);
 BEGIN
       I_PRODUCT_ := ',' || nvl(I_PRODUCT,'') || ',';
       Open  O_Cursor FOR
       SELECT * FROM Table1    WHERE 1=1
       And (I_PRODUCT_ = ',,' Or I_PRODUCT_ Like '%,' || I_PRODUCT  ||',%');
  END;
 END ProcedureName;
```

Comment: I have the PRODUCT Column with values RETAIL and LEASE. The IN params I'm using to query is `R%,L%`. It may query `R%` or `L%` or `R%,L%`. I think your code query all of them, right?

Answer (score 0):

use `IN` instead of `like`;

```
Table1.PRODUCT IN( 
    select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
```